# Name a list from a variable

Tags: python, string, list

I would like to name a new list from a string in a list, for example if I have a string 'A' create the list A[].

In my case :

```
fieldList = ["A", "B","C","D"]

for field in fieldList:
    listname = "data_{0}".format(field)
    print listname
```

I want 4 new lists

```
data_A=[]
data_B=[]
data_C=[]
data_D=[]
```

It seems easy but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want this? How will you refer to these variables afterwards?

Comment: Dynamically creating variables in Python is possible, but it's quirky. Is there a specific reason why you can't use a ``dict`` instead?